# AngularJS: How to use ng-idle

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My current scenario is:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl'});
}
```

this is my curernt `.config()` how can i integrate bellow code to my uper code:

```
.config(function(IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) {
  IdleProvider.idle(10*60); // 10 minutes idle
  IdleProvider.timeout(30); // after 30 seconds idle, time the user out
  KeepaliveProvider.interval(5*60); // 5 minute keep-alive ping
})
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {
        // end their session and redirect to login
    });
});
```

I'm newbie in angularJS. P.S thumbup the question to encourage me to ask questions here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'integrate below code'?

Comment: @Chanthu: Sir Check my [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/bDDgTYY65oGD6xl9rnIg?p=preview) I want to add idleprovider function into my `.config()` .

Comment: i want to use ng-idle to my current scenario

Comment: Can't you just do:

`myApp.config(function(IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) { })`

I'm not sure where IdleProvider is coming from. Is it some sort of a library or is that a provider written by you?

Comment: @TechKid Take  a look at the steps given here https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/

Comment: @Chanthu i just have seen example by googling that some was using that code. This is why i asked this question :P

Answer (score 5):

Like @Pankaj said, you can add ng-idle  as a script dependency, load the module 'ngIdle' and add the config to your application.

`var myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ngIdle']);`

Have a look at your modified Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/DWKdi0QsWdrO4jqlRP6l?p=preview